# Purchased object wont work in quick liquid simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, effects

I bought a brick on blendermarket and want to melt it with a simulation (quick effects/quick liquid). But for some reason, it does not work with this object. I have tested two other objects (a cube and a sphere) in the domain. For them, it works, but the brick does nothing. Thanks for your help.

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-e08he93Nrk)

Comment: Please don't upload blend files to sites that require registration to download. Use https://pasteall.org/blend/ and put a link to it in your question.

Comment: it doesnt, it's wetransfer, its free and no registration is required!

Comment: Ok. But I'm not agreeing to their terms of service without reading them by which time I've lost interest!

Comment: You're a free man, John. You can do whatever you're interested in.

Comment: Phew! :^) Actually I've seen other blend files posted on that site which haven't required me to agree the T & Cs so I'm not sure why yours did. Anyhow you have yor answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fluid objects must be manifold meshes, else it won't work.

Your brick is non-manifold:

[image]

You can check "is planar"

[image]

to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Auf dich ist einfach verlass! Danke!

Comment: Sehr gerne!!!!!!